# BigO Notation, understanding

Tags: big-o

I had seen in one of the videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A03oI0znAoc&t=470s) that, If suppose f(n)= 2n +3, then BigO is  O(n).

Now my question is if I am a developer, and I was given O(n) as upperbound of f(n), then how I will understand, what exact value is the upper bound. Because in 2n +3, we remove 2 (as it is a constant) and 3 (because it is also a constant). So, if my function is f(n) where n = 1, I can't say g(n) is upperbound where n = 1.

1 cannot be upperbound for 1. I find hard understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a partial (and probably wrong answer)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation),

> Big O notation characterizes functions according to their growth rates: **different functions with the same growth rate may be represented using the same O notation**.

In your example, 
f(n) = 2n+3 has the same growth rate as f(n) = n

If you plot the functions, you will see that both functions have the same linear growth; and as n -> infinity, the difference between the 2 gets minimal.

In Big O notation, f(n) = 2n+3 when n=1 means nothing; you need to look at the trend, not discreet values.

Comment: Thank you max got it. We need to see it’s growth (when we plot in graph), for a given value of f(n), how the g(n) grows.

Comment: Be aware that the difference between `f(n)=2n+3` and `f(n)-n` is `n+3` which is not "minimal", it is in fact greater than the second function.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia , sorry, I did not get it. So here you say, O(n) is not the right one for 2n +3 ?

Comment: It is totally right to say that `2n+3` is `O(n)`. I was reacting to @Max's sentence: _[...] as `n -> infinity`, the difference between the 2 gets minimal_. Why? Because the difference between two `O(n)` is usually `O(n)` and therefore hardly "minimal".

Comment: Looking at the difference between two O(n) functions is not the right measure. Instead what's important is that O(n^2)/O(n) goes to infinity as n goes to infinity. This happens any time the numerator has higher complexity than the denominator. No matter what constants are used in the O(n) function, an O(n^2) function will always win out in the end. You could have (10^-100 * n^2) / (10^100 * n). It doesn't matter. A googol times n isn't enough to beat n^2.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you will consider big-O as a first indication for deciding which algorithm to use. If you have an algorithm which is say, `O(n^2)`, you will try to understand whether there is another one which is, say, `O(n)`. If the problem is inherently `O(n^2)`, then the big-O notation will not provide further help and you will need to use other criterion for your decision. However, if the problem is not inherently `O(n^2)`, but `O(n)`, you should discard any algorithm that happen to be `O(n^2)` and find an `O(n)` one.

So, the big-O notation will help you to better classify the problem and then try to solve it with an algorithm whose complexity has the same big-O. If you are lucky enough as to find 2 or more algorithms with this complexity, then you will need to ponder them using a different criterion.